# Why is "pdo support is NOT loaded" being echoed after I have modified php.ini file to enabled extension=php_pdo.dll, extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll?

Tags: php, mysql, windows

Why is "pdo support is NOT loaded" being echoed after I have modified php.ini file to enabled extension=php_pdo.dll, extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll?

The IIS was restarted and the server was rebooted but the extensions don't seem to load. Is there a solution for this?  See site: http://ertowing.com/test/phptest.php.

Comment: It is the right file that is being edited and the extension directory has relevant extensions (.dll), and IIS was stopped and started again.  But no change...Is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to check to be sure that you are editing right php.ini file:

```
<?php
    echo 'The loaded file path is :' . php_ini_loaded_file();
?>
```

When you find out that, check your extension_dir inside php.ini make sure that extension directory has relevant extension .dll files.

And just for sake of testing, do stop/start of of your webserver, instead of restart.